# Rate as probability in R, Error in -r : invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r

I have a vector with mortality rates and I am trying to convert rates to probabilities.

But I get an error:

```
Error in -r : invalid argument to unary operator
```

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(darthtools)


cycle_length <- 1
n_age_init <-65
n_age_max <- 100
n_t <- n_age_max - n_age_init
n_cycles <- (n_age_max - n_age_init)/cycle_length

Mortality_2021 <- read.csv("C:\\Mortality_table_CSV.csv", sep = ";") 

v_r_mort_by_age <- Mortality_2021 %>% 
  select(Total) %>%
  as.matrix()
names(v_r_mort_by_age) <- Mortality_2021$Age


v_r_HDage  <- v_r_mort_by_age[(n_age_init + 1) + 0:(n_cycles - 1)]

v_p_HDage  <- rate_to_prob(v_r_HDage)
```

This is my data:

```
dput(head(Mortality_2021))
structure(list(Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L
), Age = 0:5, Female = c("0,00165", "0,0002", "0,0001", "0,00003", 
"0,00007", "0,00003"), Male = c("0,00203", "0,0002", "0,00013", 
"0,0001", "0,00014", "0,00006"), Total = c("0,002069453", "0,000193653", 
"4,93E-05", "0,000113588", "0,000113636", "9,71E-05")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also tried `v_p_HDage <- (1-exp(-v_r_HDage))` but I get the same error.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help!

[Data as it appears in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWx6O.png)

Comment: What is `rate_to_prob()`? Does it come from a package or is it a custom function?

Comment: Its a part of  DARTH-git/darthtools: darthtools I think :)

Comment: I don't have the same error as you when I run your code. I have `Error in if ((sum(r < 0) > 0)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Can you run the code with the data you provided and check whether you have the same error? You should use the package [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) to make reproducible examples

Comment: The numbers are in a format with comma as decimals marker, used, for instance, in continental Europe. Read the data in with `read.csv2` instead and there's no need to set `sep=";"`, this version of `read.csv` will set appropriate defaults on its own. See `?read.table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rui Barradas said in the comments, you can read in your data differently, e.g. with `read.csv2`. A base R alternative would be to replace the line:

```r
Mortality_2021 <- read.csv("C:\\Mortality_table_CSV.csv", sep = ";")
```

with the line

```
Mortality_2021 <- read.csv("C:\\Mortality_table_CSV.csv", sep = ";", dec=",")
```

If for some reason this does not work, or is not an option, you can use `readr` to parse the character vector into a number:

```r
Mortality_2021  <- Mortality_2021  |>
    mutate(across(
        Female:Total, 
        \(x) readr::parse_number(
            x,
            locale = readr::locale(decimal_mark = ",")
            )
    )
)
```

If you run this line immediately after reading in the data, the rest of your code should then work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers!

It works now when I parsed the character vector to number with your code. Is it better to use read.table way? Do you have time to show how to?